# how to call method of event in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I am trying to call method of event in ngOnInit.

```
    export class AppComponent  {
  currentMinute;addedMinute;mousemove
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){ }
  @HostListener('document:mousemove',['event'])
mouse(e){
 this.currentMinute=new Date().getMinutes();
  this.addedMinute=new Date().getMinutes()+2;
}

  ngOnInit(){
//here i want to display this.currentMinute
}
```

Just i have tried like this, but it gives undefined. How to call method of event in ngOnInit.

Comment: What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve. This sounds like an XY problem. And I also can't understand what you mean by "call function of event".

Comment: I want to call the event in ngOnInit from save(event).

Comment: What should "call an event" do exactly?

Comment: Repeating what you already said in the question won't clarify it. "calling an event" doesn't mean anything. You can call a method, not an event.

Comment: Yes I tried to call both method and event in ngOnInit but i am getting undefined. how to call that event in ngOnInit.

Comment: Explain what you **actually** want to achieve. Something like "when I click on a button, I want a label to appear". Your terminology is wrong, and the question you keep asking thus makes no sense at all.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuzzsj
In the given link i want to call this.currentMinute in ngOnInit(). But i am getting undefined

Comment: Hope you understand what i am asking. If not, just i updated my question now. Please give a look.

Comment: you are getting `this.currentMinute` undefine at ngOnInit because the `mousemove` event has not been fired yet... perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, The event is fired in mouse() but not in ngOnInit(). How can i get the event in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this reliably. After the component is created, event listener (`@HostListener`) are setup and `ngOnInit` is called by the framework. The listener will only react to the event you specify (in your case `document:mousemove`). If you wanted this value, the event would need to be fired between component creation (calling the constructor) and calling `ngOnInit`, which, as I explained, is called **immediately** after. This is nearly impossible.

In your case the workaround is pretty simple: Just do the same work in `ngOnInit` as you do in `@HostListener`:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    public currentMinute:number;
    public addedMinute:number;

    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){ }

    @HostListener('document:mousemove',['event'])
    public mouse(e):void {
        this.setDates();
    }

    public ngOnInit():void {
        this.setDates();

        // Here this.currentMinute and this.addedMinute are defined now
    }

    private setDates():void {
       this.currentMinute=new Date().getMinutes();
       this.addedMinute=new Date().getMinutes()+2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.